# GMSMapView tracking mode heading

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, gmsmapview, mkusertrackingmode

In my app, I am using `GMSMapView`, and I would like to change tracking mode. In iOS MapKit, I can change the tracking mode to `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`, but don't know how to change it in `GMSMapView`.

In the app `Google Maps`, it is working after second touch on `myLocationButton`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For continuously changing the camera with the current location, you will need to update the GMSCamera for google maps to current location. You can do it in Location Manager delegate method.

```
CLLocation *location;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
//Get current latitude and longitude from didUpdateLocation
    location = [locations lastObject];
}



-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:location.coordinate.latitude longitude:location.coordinate.longitude zoom:10 bearing:newHeading.trueHeading viewingAngle:0];
//You can change viewingAngle from 0 to 45
    [self.mapForView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
}
```

In case your delegate is not getting called, take help from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682999/for-google-maps-ios-sdk-current-location-occasionally-gets-plotted-at-0-0/31739219#31739219)

Hope it helps.

Comment: You dont understand my question.

Comment: Open Google maps app, then click on myLocation button, it move to your position, then click on button again and you will see map with different perspective(you can rotate with mobile phone)

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your requirement. Please check.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)