# Rotate GMSMapView based on compass

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, rotation

I'm working on an app where manual interaction with map is not allowed. The only way to change the map is as user is moving towards a direction. So if a user rotates the phone rotates and so based on the compass in iPhone the map should rotate automatically rather than user rotating it to the direction by 2 fingers gestures. Here is a picture that clear the idea a little more:
[image]
Consider the red dot as my location and as I rotate my phone I want google map to rotate with it. So my question is that how this can be achieved? As there is a method I found `[_myMap animateToViewingAngle:45];` after searching but this didn't did what I was looking for.

**EDIT** I thought of this is there any way we can convert lat and long values to angle?

Comment: Please refer to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208747/gmsmapview-tracking-mode-heading/38209077#38209077

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `course` property from the `CLLocation` and pass it to the `animateToBearing` method of your `GMSMapView`. From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/course):

> **Swift**
>
> ```
> var course: CLLocationDirection { get }
> ```
>
> **Objective-C**
>
> ```
> @property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationDirection course
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Course values are measured in degrees starting at due north and continuing clockwise around the compass. Thus, north is 0 degrees, east is 90 degrees, south is 180 degrees, and so on. Course values may not be available on all devices. A negative value indicates that the direction is invalid.