# Custom myLocationButton Google maps iOS SKD

Tags: ios, google-maps, location

Is there one way to customize myLocationButton GoogleMaps ? I want to add my own button with a background image which make the same function as the original Google button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your Application needs to get current location using CLLocation Manager. If you don't know how, refer to my answer here : [For google maps iOS sdk, current location occasionally gets plotted at 0,0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682999/for-google-maps-ios-sdk-current-location-occasionally-gets-plotted-at-0-0/31739219#31739219)

Now for button press action, do this

```
- (void)locationButtonPressed
{
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                            longitude:self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                 zoom:self.mapView.camera.zoom];
    [self.gMapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
}
```

Hope that helps.